# TinyMCE menus don't show

Tags: tinymce

I'm trying to get TinyMCE to work for my site at https://nicer.app/apps/eyJjbXMiOnsicGFnZSI6ImluZGV4In19

But for some reason, the menus won't show.
Not for their simple example code, nor for their full-featured example code.

I'd love some pointers on what i'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
menubar: false
```

...in your configuration so TinyMCE is just doing what you are asking it to do?

Comment: i'm trying to select a different font for instance..

Comment: I am not sure what that has to do with explicitly setting a configuration option that tells TinyMCE to not load the menubar?

Comment: the "paragraph" menu on the "toolbar" is also a drop down menu, and the only menu i'm interested in..

Answer (score 1):

with help from the bug reporting section at github, the problem was localized to my usage of overflow:hidden on the HTML tag instead of the BODY tag.

changing this fixed the problem :)